# thread stoping "his brothers" when its job is done

Tags: java, multithreading

giving the following

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MB5Returner extends Thread {

    private int startPoint;
    private int endPoint;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = startPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
            try {
                String val = Words.allPossible.get(i);
                MessageDigest m;

                m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                m.update(val.getBytes(), 0, val.length());
                String hashed = new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);

            //  System.out.println("MD5 = " + hashed);
                checkMD5(hashed, val);

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FoundMD5Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private void checkMD5(String hashed, String val) throws FoundMD5Exception {
        if (hashed.equals(Main.hashedPassword)) {
            throw new FoundMD5Exception(hashed, val);
        }
    }

    public MB5Returner(int startPoint, int endPoint) {
        super();
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

}
```

I'm making few of threads like this one. How can I stop all of them if my exception `FoundMD5Exception` was catched in one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to create an [`AtomicBoolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) (call it `keepRunning` or something similar). Pass it as a reference to the constructor of `MB5Returner`:

```
public class MB5Returner extends Thread {

    // ...
    private AtomicBoolean keepRunning;

    MB5Returner(AtomicBoolean keepRunning) {
        this.keepRunning = keepRunning;
    }
```

Change the for-loop into

```
for (int i = startPoint; keepRunning.get() && i < endPoint; i++) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then simply do

```
    // ...
} catch (FoundMD5Exception e) {
    keepRunning.set(false);
}
```

Comment: If you create multiple instances of MB5Returner, then keepRunning will not be shared amongst them. Did you mean to make it static?

Comment: I meant that he could have put it as a member variable in some shared object. However, I've updated my answer.

Comment: you probably mean `keepRunning.set(false)`

Comment: @dantuch: You should make keepRunning a static member of your MB5Returner-Class. That way you have the variable available any time you use this class. Also, otherwise you might forget how you got the whole mechanism working, next time you look at the code (in a few months).

Answer (score 0):

There is an interruption mechanism in java threads that you could use.

In your main thread, keep a reference to each worker thread.

Alter your workers like this:

```
for (int i = startPoint; (i < endPoint && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()); i++) {
    ...rest of code as usual
}
```

Then in your main thread, catch `FoundMD5Exception` and call `interrupt()` on each worker.